Modify numpy array of arrays
I have a numpy array of numpy arrays and I need to add a leading zero to each of the inner arrays:
a = [[1 2] [3 4] [5 6]] --> b = [[0 1 2] [0 3 4] [0 5 6]]
Looping through like this:
for item in a:
item = np.insert(item, 0, 0)
doesn't help.
Numpy.put() flattens the array, which I don't want.
Any suggestions how I accomplish this? Thanks

You can also use np.hstack, but np.insert answered below is more effectient

This question is similar to: Numpy add (append) value to each row of 2-d array. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm not sure how good that dupe target is, but I wanted to throw it out there.

np.insert - insert values along the given axis before the given indices. If axis is None then array is flattened first.
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
b = np.insert(a, 0, 0, axis=1)
print(b)

Result:
[[0 1 2]
 [0 3 4]
 [0 5 6]]

